# How to get values from string

Tags: javascript, string

I have a huge string, that is devided to two parts that looks like this:

```
     {\"Query\":\"blabla"","\"Subject\":\"gagaga"}","   
     {\"Query\":\"lalala\"","\"Subject\":\"rarara\"}","
```

and so on... (thousends of lines)

I need that in the end I will have a var that holds these values:

> data= "blabla,gagaga","lalala,rarara",....

This is my code but does not work:

```
var contentss = JSON.stringify(allFileGenesDetails1);
data="";
var Query1="";
var Subject1="";
// Parse the data

var contentEachLines = contentss.split("\n");
for (var jj = 0; jj < contentEachLines.length; jj++) {
var lineContent = contentEachLines[jj].split("\t");

var divided = lineContent[jj].split(",");
Query1= Query1+ [divided[0]];
Query1 = Query1.replace(/Query|:|{|"|\|/gi, "");

Subject1=Subject1+ divided[1];
Subject1 = Subject1.replace(/Subject|:|{|"|\|/gi, "");
data=data+"'"+ Query1+","+Subject1 +" ' " +"," ;
```

Comment: Looks like JSON - so parse it with `JSON.parse`. DO NOT try to write your own parser

Comment: just curious on why are you turning the JSON into a string instead of iterating over the JSON object, which would be much easier?

Comment: @Davidlrnt — http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: Wait, you started with an object. Why the heck are you turning it into a string? That makes no sense. Work with the object!

Comment: @DavidR — There *are* comments.

Comment: @DavidR there is no need to comment just to vote on a question

Comment: @charlietfl I meant to say, I'm seeing only downvotes not any comments, I have deleted my post though

Comment: @DavidR: There were plenty of comments when you posted that. Personally, I'd much rather see comments from the up voters.

Comment: @MattBurland Honestly, There was none!

Comment: @MattBurland I'm not the poster of this question though.

Comment: I don't know how you expect to get an answer when your source string isn't even a valid string (let alone JSON), and your output isn't either. I'm guessing you start with `allFileGenesDetails1` which is (or contains) an array. So use that. Loop over the array and build your output - whatever it's supposed to be (presumably another array?)

Comment: What is missing here is a [mcve]

Comment: @DavidR You deleted your answer 34 seconds after you had posted it. Even if a downvoter wanted to comment, they didn't have the time to do so.

Comment: @Juhana Valid point!. However if you see across most of the posts downvoters doesn't seem to enter any comments, Perhaps its time for SO to mandate that :-)

Comment: Yeah, [good luck with that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=require+comment+with+downvote).

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
var allFileGenesDetails1 = JSON.parse("[{\"Query\":\"blabla\",\"Subject\":\"gagaga\"},{\"Query\":\"lalala\",\"Subject\":\"rarara\"}]");
var data = "";
for(var i = 0; i < allFileGenesDetails1.length; i++) {
    if((i+1)==allFileGenesDetails1.length)
        data += allFileGenesDetails1[i].Query+","+allFileGenesDetails1[i].Subject;
    else
        data += allFileGenesDetails1[i].Query+","+allFileGenesDetails1[i].Subject+",";
}
console.log(data);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/murpoeL5/